# parseInt() parses number literals with exponent incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, parseint

I have just observed that the `parseInt` function doesn't take care about the decimals in case of integers (numbers containing the `e` character).

Let's take an example: `-3.67394039744206e-15`

```
> parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15)
-3
> -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19)
-3.6739e-15
> -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(2)
-0
> Math.round(-3.67394039744206e-15)
0
```

I expected that the `parseInt` will also return `0`. What's going on at lower level? Why does `parseInt` return `3` in this case (some snippets from the source code would be appreciated)?

In this example I'm using `node v0.12.1`, but I expect same to happen in browser and other JavaScript engines.

Comment: I'm also curious about `-3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19)` -- what exactly is that doing? `(-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(19)` returns a different result.

Comment: @Mark Can I ask a new question about that? :) I also noticed it.

Comment: @Mark When in parentheses, it returns the same thing, but as a string.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'd say so. It *is* a different question. It works as expected if you remove the negative sign, but not with it.

Comment: I get it. `-3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19)` is the same as `-((3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(19))` and the `-` (like `+`) implicitly converts it into a number (it’s like a shorthand for `Number()`, e. g. `+'14'` is `14` and `-'14'` is `-14`).

Comment: @Xufox Wow... I don't even know what to say about that. I get how +/- implicitly converts, but that negative sign really should have been parsed as part of the number IMO.

Comment: @Mark, yes, but the [order of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) has a different opinion and you’d better trust the decisions made back then about that, because otherwise it would _most likely_ mess other things up or make things _way_ harder. =P Imagine a world in which `obj.a-obj.b` would result in `ReferenceError: a is not defined` or something like that…

Comment: Isn't `parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15) === -3`?

Comment: Node v0.12.2 returns -3 and -0 instead of your 3 and 0.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Same here, but the example was wrong. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the reason is [`parseInt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) converts the passed value to string by calling [`ToString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8) which will return `"-3.67394039744206e-15"`, then parses it so it will consider `-3` and will return it.

The [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses
>   it, and returns an integer or NaN

Comment: Looks like it - from Mozilla docs at least: "If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed."

Comment: So the exponent is basically completely ignored?

Comment: Yeah.. this is so that `parseInt("200USD")` will return `200` rather than failing or throwing.  Handy feature, if you understand how it works.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan yes.... So I think the cause of this behavior is the the conversion of the number to string

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks! And one more point: the link to the source code where these things happen. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

#### `parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15) === -3`

The [`parseInt` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) expects a string as the first argument. JavaScript will call `toString` method behind the scene if the argument is not a string. So the expression is evaluated as follows:

```
(-3.67394039744206e-15).toString()
// "-3.67394039744206e-15"
parseInt("-3.67394039744206e-15")
// -3
```

#### `-3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19) === -3.6739e-15`

This expression is parsed as:

- [Unary `-` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7)
- The number literal `3.67394039744206e-15`
- `.toFixed()` -- property accessor, property name and function invocation

The way number literals are parsed is [described here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3). Interestingly, **+/- are not part of the number literal**. So we have:

```
// property accessor has higher precedence than unary - operator
3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19)
// "0.0000000000000036739"
-"0.0000000000000036739"
// -3.6739e-15
```

Likewise for `-3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(2)`:

```
3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(2)
// "0.00"
-"0.00"
// -0
```

Answer (score 3):

If the parsed string (stripped of +/- sign) contains any character that is not a radix digit (10 in your case), then a substring is created containing all the other characters before such character discarding those unrecognized characters.

In the case of `-3.67394039744206e-15`,  the conversion starts and the radix is determined as base 10 -> The conversion happens till it *encounters '.' which is not a valid character in base 10* - Thus, effectively, the conversion happens for `3` which gives the value 3 and then the sign is applied, thus -3.

For implementation logic - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2

More Examples -

```js
alert(parseInt("2711e2", 16));
alert(parseInt("2711e2", 10));
```

TO note:

*The radix starts out at base 10.*

*If the first character is a '0', it switches to base 8.*

*If the next character is an 'x', it switches to base 16.*

Comment: So wait, `e` is not regarded as an exponent because it _could_ be a hexadecimal 14?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's how it strips the string, based on the radix. And by default, the radix is 10.

Comment: @Seram: Actually, by default the radix is auto-detected based on javascript's notations for integers. For example `"0x12"` is detected as hexadecimal while `"012"` is detected as octal and `"12"` is detected as decimal

Comment: @Seram: Hmm.. it looks like `parseInt()` no longer detect leading zeros as octal. It used to do that

Comment: @Seram, true - it's detected based on the first characters encountered. My mistake there. :)

Comment: @Xufox: I mentioned that. Besides, the latest spec is still ES5. ES6 is still a few months away from being finalized

Comment: It is  assumed to be 10 if you are passing decimal number

Comment: It stops at '.' not 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

It tries to parse strings to integers. My suspicion is that your floats are first getting casted to strings. Then rather than parsing the whole value then rounding, it uses a character by character parsing function and will stop when it gets to the first decimal point ignoring any decimal places or exponents.

Some examples here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` has the purpose of parsing a string and not a number:

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an
>   integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral
>   systems).

And `parseInt` calls the function `ToString` wherein all the non numerical characters are ignored.

You can use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), which also parses strings, and *rounds a number to the nearest integer*:

```
Math.round("12.2e-2") === 0 //true
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round("12.2e-2")` may round up or down based on the value. Hence may cause issues.

`new Number("3.2343e-10").toFixed(0)` may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to calculate using parseFloat, this will give you the correct answer.

`parseInt` as it says, returns an integer, whereas `parseFloat` returns a floating-point number or exponential number:

```
parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15) = -3
parseFloat(-3.67394039744206e-15) = -3.67394039744206e-15
```

```js
console.log('parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15) = ' , parseInt(-3.67394039744206e-15));
console.log('parseFloat(-3.67394039744206e-15) = ',parseFloat(-3.67394039744206e-15));
```