# Using parenthesis when calling toFixed for negative integer values (less decimals than the power)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tofixed

In a related question I asked [parseInt() parses number literals with exponent incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30160919/1420197)

[@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160919/why-parseint-doesnt-consider-the-integer-values-less-decimals-than-the-power#comment48428796_30160919) noticed that calling `toFixed` on negative integers (numbers containing the *e* character) returns a number instead of a string, when not using parenthesis.

Let's see an example:

- Negative inputs, without parenthesis

  ```
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(19)
  -3.6739e-15
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(3)
  -0
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(14)
  -0
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(15)
  -4e-15
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(16)
  -3.7e-15
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(17)
  -3.67e-15
  > -3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(18)
  -3.674e-15
  ```
- Negative, with parenthesis

  ```
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(19)
  '-0.0000000000000036739'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(18)
  '-0.000000000000003674'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(17)
  '-0.00000000000000367'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(16)
  '-0.0000000000000037'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(15)
  '-0.000000000000004'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(14)
  '-0.00000000000000'
  > (-3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(13)
  '-0.0000000000000'
  ```
- Positive, with(out) parenthesis

  ```
  > 3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(14)
  '0.00000000000000'
  > 3.67394039744206e-15.toFixed(15)
  '0.000000000000004'
  > (3.67394039744206e-15).toFixed(16)
  '0.0000000000000037'
  ```
- Negative, but without exponent

  ```
  > -3.toFixed(3)
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
      at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
      at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
      at bound (domain.js:254:14)
      at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
      at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
      at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
      at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
      at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
      at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
      at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
  ```

Why is this happening? Is this expected?  I would be curious seeing some snippets of code which handle this (e.g. in the v8 engine).

Comment: The last case is surely expected, because the parser expects the fractional parts of a number after a period. The proper way of writing that is: `-3..toFixed(3)` (note the double period)

Comment: I don't know what to say but for me the first example is very unexpected, the interesting thing is that firefox has the same behavior