# Why different output for parseInt("10e+1") and parseFloat("10e+1") in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I tried to explore difference between pareseInt(), parseFloat() and Number() I absorbed this difference.

```
parseInt("10e+1"); // 10
parseFloat("10e+1"); // 100
Number ("10e+1"); // 100
```

When I read the document about parseFloat() on Mozilla web docs, I understood that the parseFloat() will accept exponent. Where as there is no specific point about this for parseInt(). I am very much interested to know why this difference in these similar methods

Comment: Your question contains the answer; `parseInt()` is just different from `parseFloat()` and it only pays attention plain digits, returning an integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parseInt() parses number literals with exponent incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160919/parseint-parses-number-literals-with-exponent-incorrectly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between parseInt() and parseFloat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812863/difference-between-parseint-and-parsefloat)

Comment: @Pointy i am not compromised with your answer. Can yoy explain me bit more?

Comment: Have you checked the other questions mentioned in the other answers? `parseInt()` only looks at digits. Any other character, like a "." or "e", causes it to stop parsing and return the integer it's seen so far in the source string. That's just the way it works.

Answer (score 3):

parseInt does not understand exponantial notation. However it can parse number in a string which is a number concatenated with characters. Following will also return 10 :

```
parseInt("10something")
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript provides two methods for converting non-number primitives into numbers: `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` . As you may have guessed, the former converts a value into an integer whereas the latter converts a value into a floating-point number.

- `"10e+1"` is a string, and `parseInt()` does not recognize exponential notation, so it stops at the second letter.
- `10e+1` is a number literal that evaluates to 100; `parseInt()` sees
  `100` and happily returns that.
- `"10e+1"` as a string is perfectly fine when parsed as a `float`.

**Example:**

```js
console.log( 'parseInt( 10e+1 ) return: ' + parseInt( 10e+1 ) );
console.log( 'parseInt( "10e+1" ) return: ' + parseInt( '10e+1' ) );
console.log( 'parseFloat( 10e+1 ) return: ' + parseFloat( 10e+1 ) );
console.log( 'parseFloat( "10e+1" ) return: ' + parseFloat( '10e+1' ) );
```